# Set a UIViewController's title with a NSMutableArray item

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, title

Is it possible to set the title of a `UIViewController` by an array item? For example if I have an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` list of food, click the food name and that then becomes the title in the loaded View?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an array of food names, such as:

```
NSArray *foodArr = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Chicken",@"Cheese",@"Hamburger"]
```

and you want the title to be "Cheese" (the object at index 1), you need to obtain the NSString from within the array:

```
NSString *foodTitle = [foodArr objectAtIndex:1];
```

then you can set your title to that string:

```
self.navigationController.title = foodTitle;
```

Comment: You could also say that the `UIViewController` has to be wrapped within a `UINavigationController`. cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this, if you have an array of strings do:

```
yourViewController.title = [self.myNameArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
```

if you have an array of objects with a title property:

```
yourViewController.title = [[self.myObjectArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] title];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use UINavigationController with NavigationBar you can easy do follow:

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

   self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithString:@"%@",[yourTitles objectAtIndex:yourIndex];

}
```

If you do not use it, then you`ll have manually add UILabel that will present your title and do the same :

```
-(void) viewDidLoad {

   [titleLabel setText:[NSString stringWithString:@"%@",[yourTitles objectAtIndex:yourIndex]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes very simple

```
//Assuming you are displaying food item in tableView
//vController is class object which is going to be pushed on navigation stack
//Put this line in didSelectRowAtIndexPath method

yourViewControllerObject.title = [foodItemArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```